# Call a method associated with partial rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials

In my controller I have this method that retuns to me the list of specific books controller/books_controller

```
  def postings
    @books = Book.postings(current_user.id).order("created_at ASC")
    render :partial =>'postings'
  end
```

I have a partial in views/books/_postings.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<h4>My Partial Postings</h4>
 <% @books.each do |book| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="<%= book.image_path %>" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h4 class="nomargin"><%= book.title %></h4>
          <p><%= book.description %></p>
          <p>Quantity: <%= book.quantity %></p>
          <p>Available for: <%= book.sale_type %></p>
     </div>
     </div>
     <hr>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

In my routes :

```
 resources :books do
    collection do
      get 'postings'
    end
  end
```

on running rake routes :

```
 postings_books GET  /books/postings(.:format)  books#postings
```

When I use localhost:3000/books/postings I get the desired partial showing list of books .But when I want to call this partial from some other view eg from localhost:3000/dashboard/index:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="postings">
                    <%= render  'books/postings', :collection => @books %>
</div>
```

I get the following error:

```
 Showing /home/swati/867/WorkSpace2/assignment_3/app/views/books/_postings.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #4):
<div class="container">
<h4>My Partial Postings</h4>
 <% @books.each do |book| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="<%= book.image_path %>" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
```

I understand that render is just rendering the partial without calling my method postings in books_controller and my partial has no access to @books , which is nil. How can aprroach this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `dashboard/index` you are actually calling `index` method of `dashboards_controller`. If you would like to render the `books/postings` partial there, you need to add the list of books (`@books`) in that controller too.

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Thanks yes I realized that , I actually moved the method postings from books_controller to dashboard_controller. I am still trying to usderstand MVC . but i just read somewhere that controller should be associated with view. So if i wanted to access postings method from views of dashboard , it was better to have that method in dashboard_controller instead of books_controller. I am not sure if what i did was ideal but it works well.

Comment: Also just to add a point for novice users of rails like me :) , if you njeed to access a method in the views , you need to use helper_method .. so in my contoller i have   helper_method :postings ,and from my view i can call the method.